# monitoring CAS login system

Tags: login, system-monitoring, cas

I have a CAS (Central Authentication System) that uses ADFS to authenticate user. First user go to a webapp, click login, which redirects it to CAS. If user is authenticated, it redirects back to webapp, else it will send it to ADFS and authenticate user and return to CAS and then to webapp. I am looking for a method to monitor this system so that I will know before it breaks or immediately after it breaks.
I tried using HTTP transaction sensor of PRTG but no luck.

Comment: I end up writing powershell script!

Comment: Please share how you have CAS use ADFS to authenticate! I need to implement the same and the internet has a dearth of good explanations of that topic.